# Intelllij doesn't support Play Framework very well?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I am using Intellij Idea + Scala Plugin + Play framework 2.6.0 to do web development.

I have a FruitController, its definition is:

```
  def saveFruit = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
    import FruitImplicits._
    val fruitResult = request.body.validate[Fruit]
    fruitResult.fold(
      errors => {
        BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "KO", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors)))
      },
      fruit => {
        println(s"Fruit is saved, the result is :$fruit")
        Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "OK", "message" -> ("Fruit '" + fruit.name + "' saved.")))
      }
    )
  }
```

The Intellij idea complains `Missing parameter type:request` for the `request` in the first line: `Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>`

But I could run the code successfully, so Intellij Idea has been mistakenly reported the error, I would ask how to get Intellij Idea to work well for this code

Comment: You should have scala compiler configured and all dependancies present. I have been using idea with play framework for now almost 2 years without any issues..

Comment: @SouravGanguly I think i have well set  scala compiler configured and all dependancies, because I can run this controller in Intellij Idea

Comment: Intellij doesn't support Scala that well, use SBT as your source of truth for error checking.

Comment: @puhlen can you elaborate? Intellij is **the** state of the art scala IDE. Every alternative to date has less features.

Comment: @JulianLiebl Intellij does not use the scala compiler to check your code, as such, it does not match up 1 to 1 and it will report errors for valid code.  While it works in many cases there are times where intellij will choke. I like Intellij a lot and most of the the it works well for the code I write but there are times that it breaks.  Features are nice but correctness is more important.

Comment: @puhlen That is true. However most of the time it works amazingly well. I wouldn't call that "Intellij doesn't support Scala that well". I guess it depends on the use case. Thank you for elaborating!

Answer (score 0):

When I explicitly specify the type of the `request: Request[JsValue]`, the problem is gone:

```
  def saveFruit = Action(parse.json) { request: Request[JsValue] =>
```